# how to hide a file using adobe AIR?

Tags: air

I am using both windows and MAC.there is a file in desktop.I want that when my air application fires up itself it will hide that file.Please help with some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

I would believe that you need to package a native application that performs the hiding. See [Communicating with native processes in AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html) and also [Introducing the Adobe AIR security model](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/introduction_to_air_security.html). Also, there is no guarantee that a file is truly hidden. A Windows user might've choosen to always display hidden files, similar with dotfiles on OSX/Linux.

Comment: +1.  perhaps the OP might consider temporarily moving the file to the applicationStorage directory and restoring the file to the desktop during the native application exiting routine.